# Indexing with simple expression broken in Apache Camel 2.18

Tags: apache-camel

The following sample code works fine with all versions of Camel, excluding 2.18.x

```
from("direct:process")
        .process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) {
                List<String> alist = new ArrayList<String>();
                alist.add("1");
                alist.add("99");
                exchange.getIn().setHeader("ITEMS", alist);
                exchange.getIn().setHeader("TOTAL_LOOPS", alist.size());
            }
        })
        .loop(simple("${header.TOTAL_LOOPS}", Integer.class))
          .setHeader("item", simple("${header.ITEMS[${property.CamelLoopIndex}]}", String.class))
          .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOG_CLASS_NAME, simple("item = ${header.item} and TOTAL_MAPS = ${header.TOTAL_LOOPS}").getText())
        .end()
        .end();
```

However with 2.18.x, the following exception gets thrown:

> 2017-02-03 21:13:31 ERROR DefaultErrorHandler:204 - Failed delivery
>   for (MessageId: ID-CATL0W10D4DG4R1-55822-1486174410756-0-1 on
>   ExchangeId: ID-CATL0W10D4DG4R1-55822-1486174410756-0-2). Exhausted
>   after delivery attempt: 1 caught:
>   org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException: Failed
>   to invoke method: [${property.CamelLoopIndex}] on java.util.ArrayList
>   due to: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Key:
>   ${property.CamelLoopIndex} not found in bean: [1, 99] of type:
>   java.util.ArrayList using OGNL path [[${property.CamelLoopIndex}]]

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: Currently we are using Camel 2.17.4 (JDK 1.7) and this expression works correctly. We wish to migrate to 2.18.2 or later (JDK1.8)  and found out that this expression throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Can you log a JIRA ticket

Comment: JIRA ticket opened:https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10789

Comment: I am having the same problem after migrating from 2.17.1 to 2.24.3  @ClausIbsen